# Legend transition not working properly

Tags: d3.js

I have a graph with a legend, and the legend is always the same. The only thing that changes with the transitions is the size of the legend tiles, that are the same as this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084).

When I update my graph, its size changes, and so does the legend's. Here is what I have for the legend :

```
var couleurs = ["#ffffb2", "#fed976", "#feb24c", "#fd8d3c", "#fc4e2a", "#e31a1c", "#b10026"];
var legende = ["0-15", "15-30", "30-45", "45-60", "60-75", "75-90", "90-100"];

    canevas.append("g").selectAll(".legende").data(legende).enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "legende")
        .attr("width", cellPosX / 7)
        .attr("height", largeurCellule / 2)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (cellPosX / 7))
        .attr("y", cellPosY + 10)
        .attr("fill", ((d, i) => couleurs[i]));

    canevas.selectAll(".legende").data(legende).transition()
        .duration(transitionTime)
        .attr("width", cellPosX / 7)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => i * (cellPosY / 7))
        .attr("y", cellPosY + 10)
        .attr("fill", ((d, i) => couleurs[i]));

    canevas.selectAll(".legende").data(legende).exit()
        .remove();
```

This works fine, except that when the graph is updated, for a while there are 2 legends at the same time. One that goes from the old position to the new one, which is expected, but there is also one that instantly appears to the new position. [Here is a very low fps gif](http://g.recordit.co/FPLRapINf7.gif) that I quickly made to show an example.

How would I go about having the legend going from its initial position to the other one, without it also appearing instantly at the new position?

Comment: Are you running this `.append("g".selectAll(".legende").data(legende).enter()` each time you update? If so, this will append new features each time as you are creating a new creating a new `g` that won't have any `.legende` elements, and thus will `.enter` will create new ones every time.

Comment: @AndrewReid yes I was, thanks !